# How to adding validation in nested array with different FormGroup in angular

Tags: angular, validation, nested, formarray

I have a nested array item list. I would like to add validation in "Apple Phone (If applicable)" (On the top) as required field if some items selected "Apple" in "Electronic device". The problem is how to control the validation in different form Group. Any one can help ?

Bellow image is what i want validation. I want to trigger a error message when any item selected "Apple"in "Electronic device". [Here is stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-exbbbs?file=src/app/app.component.html)

[image]

Comment: Like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhijrw?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @hrdkisback This works really well. Yes, it is what i want to add. However, it seem to be not work when ngOnInit(). It seem to work the selection box on change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before to create a custom validator, we need take account that Angular only check the validation is there're an input (or a custom formControl) and the user change the value or if manually we make an updateValueAndValidity.

So if we want Angular validate a control when we change another we can take two approach

1. Use the event change in .html

   ```
   <select formControlName="device" 
          (change)="updateAppleForm.get('apple').updateValueAndValidity()">
   ```
2. subscribe to valueChange of the FormControl. That's our function
   `settypeList`becomes like

   settypeList(x) {
   let arr = new FormArray([]);

   ```
   x.typeList.forEach((y) => {
     //first we create the group
     const group=this.fb.group(
       {
         subQuota: y.subQuota,
         device: y.device,
       }
     )

     //subscribe to valueChanges
     group.get('device').valueChanges.pipe(
             takeUntil(this.active))
      .subscribe(_=>{
         setTimeout(()=>{
           this.updateAppleForm.get('apple').updateValueAndValidity();
         })
    })

     //and push the group
     arr.push(group);
   });
   return arr;   }
   ```

See that I use a "clasic" takeWhile to unsubscribe in onDestroy.

```
  active: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(); //we decalre a subject "active"

  //and in ngOnDestroy emit a true and give as completed
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.active.next(true);
    this.active.complete();
  }
```

The second election we need take is have two or only one FormGroup. If we have an unique FormGroup we need makes some changes in our code

We define our `updateAppleForm` like

```
this.updateAppleForm = this.fb.group({
  apple: [null,this.requiredIfApple],
  sessionList: this.fb.array([])
});
```

And use a getter

```
  //instead
  //sessionListFormArr:FormArray

  //use a getter
  get sessionListFormArr(): FormArray {
    return this.updateAppleForm.get('sessionList') as FormArray;
  }
```

After in the .html we remove the `<form [formGroup]="sessionListessionDynamicForm">`

```
<div formArrayName="sessionList">
```

Well, our custom validator becomes like

```
  requiredIfApple(control:AbstractControl)
  {
    const parent=control.parent;
    if (!parent || control.value)
      return null;

      return parent.value.sessionList.find(x=>x.typeList.find(t=>t.device=='A'))?{inValidApple:"required"}:null
    
  }
```

You can see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkmawf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

But you ask about a validator that use variables of the components. For this you need use the javascript [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

You define your formGroup like

```
this.updateAppleForm = this.fb.group({
  apple: [null,this.requiredIfApple().bind(this)]
});
```

And your custom error like

```
  requiredIfApple()
  {
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
      if (!this.sessionListessionDynamicForm || control.value)
        return;
      const form=this.sessionListessionDynamicForm.get('sessionList') as FormArray
      return form.value.find(x=>
        x.typeList.find(t=>t.device=='A'))?
              {inValidApple:"required"}:null
    }
  }
```

Your [forked stackblitz with this approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l9xmbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). See that we need make an updateValueAndValidity. In this stackblitz I use the approach of use the event "change"

Comment: Nice. The Second approach is exactly what I was looking for. Simple & effective.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over FormArray.controls and use a variable in the loop, e.g.

```
*ngFor="let sessionQuota of sessionFormArr.get('typeList')['controls']
```

The variable is an "AbstractControl", so you can use `sessionQuota.errors and sessionQuota.touched`, e.g.

```
<div *ngIf="sessionQuota.errors && sessionQuota.touched">
   error
</div>
```

BTW I prefer to have a function

```
getTypeList(index){
  return this.sessionFormArr.at(index).get('typeList') as FormArray
}
```

and iterate over `getTypeList(i).controls`

```
*ngFor="let sessionQuota of getTypeList(i).controls"
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping. But sorry that i am describe very bad such that you misunderstanding my problem. I know this solution is work on add validation on electronic device if user selected 'Apple'. But I want to add a validation on "Apple Phone (If applicable)" if the user selected 'Apple' in electronic device. Do you have any idea?